# ImportError: cannot import name 'binary_type'

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, bson

I've installed BSON library to convert strings to MongoDB ObjectIds, but when I try using the library, this comes up:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "search.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pymongo.mongo_client import MongoClient
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/__init__.py", line 90, in <module>
    from pymongo.common import (MIN_SUPPORTED_WIRE_VERSION,
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/common.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pymongo.auth import MECHANISMS
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 33, in <module>
    from bson.binary import Binary
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bson/binary.py", line 21, in <module>
    from bson.py3compat import PY3, binary_type
ImportError: cannot import name 'binary_type'
```

Also pip installs py3compat, but there's no 'binary_type' in there.
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, there is no 'binary_type' variable or function in 'bson' package. It supports only 3 types i.e. 'integer_types', 'string_type', and 'text_type'. To work with binary data you have to convert your data to binary data first

Comment: Ok, any advice on how to go from string to MongoDB ObjectId?

Comment: Try this, mongo_oid = ObjectId(string_data)

Comment: Yup, that's what I did. I used bson library to import ObjectId, and when I tried using it to convert string to ObjectId, it sent the error from the post above.

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I think I want clear the first time - before asking this question, I used ObjectId, and thats when the ImportError came up.

Comment: ObjectId class isn’t in py3compat.py it’s in objectid.py file; from bson.objectid import ObjectId ; If you are receiving the error again please share your code file and your error log

Comment: Ok, here is the code: from pymongo.mongo_client import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

con = MongoClient()
db = con.VetTrial
articles = db.articles

article_id = '5bb8e8448cbad90e5c4b31a2'

articles = list(articles.find({'_id':ObjectId(article_id)}))

And the error is the same as in the first post.

Comment: Try updating packages pymongo and bson packages, as in my pc there is no such import statement from bson.py3compat import PY3, binary_type they have removed binary_type from it

Comment: Turns out I made a mistake of installing bson library separate from pymongo. Uninstalled pymongo and bson, reinstalled pymongo, and all works well. Thanks Keshav.

Comment: Enjoy Learning 

Answer (score 1):

I saw this error and got it fixed by installing the newest version of `pymongo`.

(at the time of writing)

```
pip install pymongo==3.5.1
```